# SwiftUI overlay alignment for horizontal centering

Tags: swiftui, geometryreader

I need view A to be centered on the screen (vertically and horizontally). I need view B to appear 30px below view A, also centered horizontally. But A must remain in the center of the screen, without moving upward when B is added. I can accomplish most of this by using `.overlay` and `GeometryReader`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.red)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                    .overlay {
                        GeometryReader {geo in
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(.blue)
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                .offset(y: geo.size.height + 30)
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I don't know how to center the blue Rectangle horizontally though. I don't necessarily know its width, although it's specified here for visual purposes. Assuming I don't know the exact frame values for either view, how I can I position B 30px below A while keeping A in the center of the screen? And is there a better view structure for accomplishing this?

Comment: You said "I don't know the exact frame", but how can you design a UI without knowing its size or position? it's hard to imagine.

Comment: I mean, most UI in SwiftUI is done without knowing the exact sizes of the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a `VStack` with a *hidden* copy of the blue rectangle above the red one:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    private var blueRectangle: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.blue)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            blueRectangle.hidden()
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.red)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
            blueRectangle
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Alternatively, if the blue rectangle is not expected to be wider than the red one then here's how you could do it with an overlay:

```swift
var body: some View {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(.red)
        .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
        .overlay(alignment: .top) {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                blueRectangle
                    .frame(maxWidth: proxy.size.width)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    .offset(y: proxy.size.height + 30)
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I chuckled a bit at the first one, but that trick may come in handy in the future :)
The alternative works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it sounds pretty obvious, but the red rectangle is vertically centered using `.alignmentGuide(.center)`, while the blue rectangle is aligned below it by calculating its vertical position relative to the `red rectangle's height + 30-pixel offset`. Both rectangles inherit horizontal centering within the ZStack, ensuring they remain centered on the screen as below

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                    .alignmentGuide(.center) { _ in
                        0
                    }
                    .overlay {
                        GeometryReader { geo in
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(Color.blue)
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                .alignmentGuide(.center) { _ in
                                    geo.size.height + 30
                                }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile due to "Reference to member 'vertical' cannot be resolved without a contextual type"

Comment: humm, SwiftUI 3.0 ? I did an update in the alignmentGuide, as alternative